# Ruby confluence4r examples

Tags: ruby, api, wiki, xml-rpc, confluence

I cannot find where to download the confluence4r gem and it doesn't work when I do:

```
gem install confluence4r
```

I downloaded one here: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/Confluence4r

I can login

```
server = Confluence::RPC.new("http://wiki/")
server.login("username","password")
```

but once I do anything else it fails

```
server.getSpace("key")
```

but wait.. I do it a 2nd time and it works...

```
server.getSpace("key")

{"name"=>"key example", "homePage"=>"235325", "url"=>"http://wiki/display/key", "type"=>"global", "description"=>"description example", "key"=>"key"}
```

Here's the error I receive on the first try before making it work on the 2nd try:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
```

from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in`rbuf_fill'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in`timeout'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in`readuntil'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2024:in`read_status_line'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2013:in `read_new'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1050:in`request'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:992:in `post2'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:538:in`do_rpc'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:420:in `call2'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:410:in`call'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:617:in `send'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:617:in`method_missing'
 from ./confluence4r.rb:35:in `send'
 from ./confluence4r.rb:35:in`method_missing'

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

### **EDIT**

Okay, I'm using part of this gem instead and it works fine:

```
gem install confluencer
@api = Confluence::Client.new(:url => "http://wiki")
@api.login("username","password")
user = @api.getUser("username")
pp user

{"name"=>"username",
 "url"=>"http://wiki/display/~username",
 "fullname"=>"Full Name",
 "email"=>"EmailAddress@example.com"}
```

now the problem is I am unable to add anything, but I can do gets and thats it.  It just hangs and I believe continues to do a retry over and over again.  Maybe my wiki is broken..

```
create_user = @api.createUser("username","password","First LastName","Email@example.com")
pp create_user
```

Hangs at create_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay using just XMLRPC Client now and everything is working

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'

confluence = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://wiki/rpc/xmlrpc").proxy("confluence1")
token = confluence.login("username", "password")

user = {
"name" => user_name,
"fullname" => full_name,
"email" => email
}

confluence.addUser(token, user, user_name)
```

I tested this in confluence 2.8 to 3.4 - wow that was soo much easier!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, using the confluence4r.rb code fails with Confluence v4. The simple fix is to change...
 @conf = server.proxy("confluence1")
TO
 @conf = server.proxy("confluence2")

The error message is:
confluence.rb:38:in `rescue in method_missing': java.lang.Exception: com.atlassian.confluence.rpc.RemoteException: Unsupported operation: Wiki formatted content can no longer be retrieved from this API. Please use the version 2 API. The version 2 WSDL is available at: https://wiki.globalrelay. net/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v2?wsdl. XML-RPC requests should prefixed with "confluence2.". (RuntimeError)
        from confluence.rb:31:in`method_missing'